# Android Activity Prompted before exiting

Tags: android

I'm trying to prompt the user before exiting an activity, depending on response, pass back a value to the calling activity, currently this is how i'm doing it.

```
private void quit() {
AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Have you finished ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                exit(2);

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                exit(0);
                            }
                        });
        alert = alt_bld.create();
        // Title for AlertDialog
        alert.setTitle(showString);
        // Icon for AlertDialog
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alert.show();
}
private void exit(int flag) {
    if (flag == 1) {
        setResult(Consts.QUITREMOTE);
    } else if (flag == 2) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("showID", ID);
        setResult(Consts.REMOVESHOW, i);
    }
    alert.dismiss();
    this.finish();
}
```

But this raises an excpetion because the alert dialog isn't done:

```
01-12 14:48:12.744: E/WindowManager(1081): Activity x has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405ff580 that was originally added here
```

How can i do this?

Comment: from where you are calling quit() method?

Comment: from a button, created in a buttion_create function called from onCreate

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was, i was also calling quit(false); from onDestroy.  the above code works fine if with the quit(false) removed